# I have array of array, and i want array of object in return how would I do this in JS or using underscore-plugin

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [
  [{a: "apple", b: "ball"}, {c: "cat", d: "dog"}],
  [{e: "elephent", f: "flight"}, {g: "god", h: "hen"}]
];
```

The expected result is --

```
var exp = [
  {a: "apple", b: "ball"}, 
  {c: "cat", d: "dog"},
  {e: "elephent", f: "flight"}, 
  {g: "god", h: "hen"}
]
```

Comment: `[].concat(...arr)`

Comment: @tg24 ... arr is [[],[]]

Comment: Hey Arup, you're getting downvotes and votes to close because your question doesn't show what you've tried and ask for specific help it is just asking a broad question on how to achieve something. Can you be more specific?

Comment: probably worth reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flat()`:

```js
var arr = [[{a: "apple", b: "ball"}, {c: "cat", d: "dog"}],[{e: "elephent", f: "flight"}, {g: "god", h: "hen"}]];
console.log(arr.flat());
```

for microsoft edge and IE, use `[].concat(...arr)`

Comment: wont work on any microsoft browser though - not even Edge - see **[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)** for alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You can access index `0` of array and assign it to existing variable you store your array

Something like

```
arr = arr[0]
```

*Since question was misread, this answer needs update

```
let newArr = []
newArr = arr.map((item) {
    return item[0]
})
```

This leaves `arr` unchanged. If you'd rather modify `arr` use `forEach` instead of `map`

Comment: Have you tried and compared your solution to the expected results?

Comment: He edited the question, previous array sample was [ [ {}, {}, {} ] ]

Comment: Oh right..bad sight..you can try updated answer, it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
[].concat(...arr)
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.